# Chromecast API - need help to hide volume bar when mute event applied

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm developing Chrome-cast application which will cast the media content from mobile to TV, I'm able to do that. But I have a feature like for some of the videos I need to apply mute/UN-mute events, even I'm able to apply the mute/UN-mute events.

Whenever I apply mute/UN-mute events I observed that audio icon and volume bar appears at the bottom of receiver/TV screen.

Here my concern is, do we have any way/API to hide the volume bar or audio icon when event applied?

Your help is highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot hide that on your TV; it is displayed by the platform.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Ali Naddaf. Is it possible in the case of custom receiver?

Comment: Platform means 'will it be displayed default by the TV platform?'

Comment: No, by Chromecast device.

Comment: Ok. Initially I posted query in google-cast-sdk, link: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=511. They replied me saying that its not an SDK issue and suggested me to post query in Stack Overflow.

Comment: That is correct, it is not SDK; it is part of the Chromecast platform software that runs on the Chromecast device so SDK has no access to that to control it.